# Fix header plugin not working in Angular datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datatable, fixed-header-tables

I am using the stable build version Stable release v2.1.2 of the fixed header jquery [plugin](http://datatables.net/download/#FixedHeader). I am trying to fix my table header. I have created the table using Angular datatables as mentioned over [here](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/angularWay).

In my controller class I have written the following code,

```
app.controller("SampleController", function ($scope) {

    $(document).ready( function () {
        var table = $('#example').DataTable();
        new $.fn.dataTable.FixedHeader( table );
    });

});
```

My HTML is as follows,

```
 <table id="example" datatable="ng" dt-options="dtOptions" dt-column-defs="dtColumnDefs" fix-header>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name </th>
                </tr>
               </thead>    
              <tbody> 
                   <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
                        <td>{{item.name}} </td>
                   </tr>
              </tbody>
 </table>
```

However when i run my application, i get the following error,

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined

I also tried using the following directive as I am aware that DOM manipulations should not be done in Controller but I get the following error.

> TypeError: Cannot set property '_oPluginFixedHeader' of undefined

**UPDATE:**

my directive

```
app.directive('fixHeader', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE', //attribute or element
        replace: true,
        link: function ($scope, elem, attr) {
            $scope.table = elem.find("#example");  
            console.log($scope.table);
            var table= $scope.table.dataTable(); 
            new $.fn.dataTable.FixedHeader(table); 
        }
    };
});
```

Please can someone suggest a better solution?

I am using version **2.1.2** of **dataTables.fixedHeader.js** and my error comes in below line

```
 var dt = $.fn.dataTable.Api ?
        new $.fn.dataTable.Api( mTable ).settings()[0] :
        mTable.fnSettings();

    dt._oPluginFixedHeader = this; //error over here
```

Comment: could you please upload your code or create fiddle with problem?

Comment: Please provide a full code to clarify the exact issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `angular-datatables` also provides plugin to `FixedHeader works with datatables. You need to add the files`angular-datatables.fixedheader.min.js`to your HTML. You also need to add the dependency`datatables.fixedheader` to your Angular app. then your code will look like below.

**HTML**

```
<table datatable="" dt-options="dtOptions" dt-columns="dtColumns" class="row-border">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
            <td>{{item.name}} </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**CODE**

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['datatables', 'datatables.fixedheader'])
app.controller("SampleController", function($scope, DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder) {
    $scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.fromSource('data.json')
        .withPaginationType('full_numbers')
        .withDisplayLength(25)
        .withFixedHeader({
            bottom: true
        });
    $scope.dtColumns = [
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('id').withTitle('ID'),
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('Name').withTitle('Name'),
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('Address').withTitle('Address')
    ];
});
```

No need of adding directive, because there is already directive created inside `angular-datatables.fixedheader.min.js` ([**Reference Link**](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/withFixedHeader))

**Update:**

Below changes need to be done in code.

1. Replace `FixedHeader` js code & jquery code to `new $.fn.dataTable.FixedHeader($element.find('#example'))`
2. Call that method which will set `FixedHeader`

**Controller**

```
(function(angular) {
    angular.module('showcase.angularWay', ['datatables'])
    .controller('AngularWayCtrl', AngularWayCtrl);

    function AngularWayCtrl($http, $element) {
        var vm = this;
        $http.get('data.json').then(function(res) {
            vm.persons = res.data;
            vm.setFixedHeader(); //call method to set glass.
        });

        vm.setFixedHeader = function(){
            //var table = $element.find('#example').DataTable();
            new $.fn.dataTable.FixedHeader($element.find('#example'))
        };
    }
})(angular);
```

You can also move this code to directive, only you need to remove header column which is appended as extra header.

I referred [**this link**](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/19916/using-fixedheader-without-datatables-returns-error) for above updated solution

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/x5uR0zuCO2Wz9Dl6Tn2A?p=preview)

Comment: hi Pankaj. Have you tried this with datatable = "ng". Since you have written datatable =" " in your code that means it is jquery datatable. I need it to work using angular way

Comment: When I tried it. I get another clone of my header which is fixed. The normal table header is still there.

Comment: Here an [example](http://codepen.io/l-lin/pen/xbawbm?editors=101) using the "Angular way".

Comment: @l-lin: Even i tried the same but for some reason  it creates a clone of my datatable header and hence although my header gets fixed but i can another portion of my table header moving across the page.

Comment: yes it is working with your example. If any problems. I will let u know

Comment: @ParthDoshi now the bounty also gets end :(

Comment: @pankajparkar: In your plunker, i see the header is fixed but it is also cloned. How to remove the extra header ? Also the sorting does not work in your plunker. Also, I will start a new bounty and provide you the points for the same since you have helped me solve this

Comment: hi can you email me the fix regarding the cloned header..my email is androidparth@gmail.com

Comment: @ParthDoshi I going to work on it, but I don't think so you would care if i solve your issue, You really don't care who helped you..

Comment: no it is not like that. i really appreciate your work. i think there is some misunderstanding. i am sorry if i did a mistake

Comment: let it be..As I'm always ready to help..I'll let you know if i can fix your mentioned issue

Comment: hi @pankajparkar: did u get any solution for the cloning of header?

Comment: I didn't get a time look at it.I'll look at it afterwards